# Detect empty filtercontainer NEST Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How to detect that a filtercontainer is empty? There are ways to detect if the container is Conditionless but empty does not equal conditionless. Eg something like this:

```
var filter = new FilterDescriptor<Tweet>();
Assert.That(filter.IsEmpty, Is.EqualTo(true));
```

Comment: why do you want to check that a `FilterContainer` is empty?

Comment: i'm working with some code where 1 or more filtercontainers get ORed. this mostly works but when a filtercontainer is empty it returns all the results which is not wanted

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're doing, and what the expected result is? I think there are other ways to solve your problem but need to understand what you're doing first